# while loop does not execute scanf()

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float change = 0.0;

    printf("O hai!  ");
    while (change <= 0) {
        printf("How much change is owed?\n");
        scanf("%f\n", &change);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the result if input is a negative is endless "How much change is owed?"

Comment: Can't reproduce it: if I enter a negative amount, I only get one occurrence of "How much change is owed?", not an endless series.

Comment: It asks twice for positive numbers too. Change `scanf("%f\n",&change);` ==> `scanf("%f",&change);`

Comment: Step 1 with any `scanf()` problem: Test its return value like `if (scanf("%f",&change) != 1) print_ErrorAndQuit()`

Comment: Why do you have a `\n` in the `scanf` format string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` is actually entered, but due to the `\n` in format string `"%f\n"`, after having entered a number, `scanf` waits for the next non-whitespace character to return. Note that a white space in format specifier lets `scanf` consume *a sequence* of any white space characters, not only one, and so it "hangs" as long as only white space characters are provided by the stream.

Change `scanf("%f\n",&change)` into `scanf("%f",&change)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask a computer to discard whitespace, how does it know what it's done? Answer: As soon as it reads something that's not whitespace.

You asked it to discard whitespace after reading a number. Thus it's not done until it reads the number and then reads some non-whitespace.

That really doesn't make any sense since there's no reason anyone would enter non-whitespace after entering the number.

Here's a tip though that will save you pain in the future: If what you really want to do is read a *line* of input then parse it, use a function that reads a line and then some code to parse that input.